How to find an acute angle of a right triangle inscribed in a square?
Working on

Daniel J. Velleman. (2017). "Calculus: A Rigorous First Course" (p. 66)


My question is focused on the purple circle on the image above. The solution given by the author is $\alpha$; however, I can't find out how to work out the solution by myself.
I have tried thinking in terms of angles and perpendicular lines, but the relationship between the original $\alpha$ and the solution given is not clear to me. How can I approach this ?

In the bottom triangle mark the unmarked angle as x. The bottom triangle angles sum to 180, as do the angles created at a point on a straight line. So alpha is your circled angle

$?+90+(90-\alpha)=180$
so
$?=\alpha$.

I'm afraid you're likely to kick yourself…  (This doesn't need any trigonometry, just simple angle sums.)
First, consider the angles in the bottom triangle.  Its left-hand angle is marked as $\alpha$, and its bottom-right is a right angle ($\frac{\pi}{2}$).  To find its unmarked angle, note that the angles in a triangle always add up to $\pi$, i.e.: $$α + \frac{\pi}{2} + unmarked\ angle = \pi$$
Hence: $$unmarked\ angle = \pi - \alpha - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$$
Now consider the angles around its top-right tip.  There are three, which add up to a straight line: the unmarked angle we've just found ($\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$), the right angle of the inner triangle ($\frac{\pi}{2}$), and the purple angle.  But a straight line is an angle of $\pi$, so: $$(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha) + \frac{\pi}{2} + purple\ angle = \pi$$
Therefore: $$purple\ angle = \pi - (\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha) - \frac{\pi}{2} = \alpha$$
